# More than one video view in single android activity

Tags: android

I am working on one application in which there is requirement of 4 videoviewa in one screen, the view is like four sqaure boxes in one screen 
I have taken 4 videoview in one activity
here is the code

```
vid1 = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vid1);
        vid2 = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vid2);
        vid3 = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vid3);
        vid4 = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.vid4);

private void PlayVideo() {
        lnrVideoPlayback.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Thread t1 = null, t2 = null, t3 = null, t4 = null;
        if (prefsVideo.getString("v1URI", null) != null) {

            vid1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prefsVideo.getString("v1URI", null)));
//          vid1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getResources()
//                  .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.boxviewheight),
//                  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.boxviewheight)));

            vid1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process
                            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);

                    vid1.start();

                }
            });
        }
        if (prefsVideo.getString("v2URI", null) != null) {
            vid2.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prefsVideo.getString("v2URI", null)));
            vid2.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
            vid2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process
                            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
                    vid2.start();
                }
            });
        }
        if (prefsVideo.getString("v3URI", null) != null) {
            vid3.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prefsVideo.getString("v3URI", null)));
            vid3.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
            vid3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process
                            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);
                    vid3.start();
                }
            });
        }
        if (prefsVideo.getString("v4URI", null) != null) {
            vid4.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(prefsVideo.getString("v4URI", null)));
            vid4.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
            vid4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    android.os.Process
                            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_DISPLAY);

                    vid4.start();
                }
            });
        }

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

    }
```

When i am playing single video than its played correctly, when i played 4 videos together it shows me message "Video Cant be played" in all 4 videos

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system/framework implementation of your device.

1. Max number of instance of media player that is allowed to be used at same time
2. Max number of video surface that is allowed to be used at same time

Normally, the number is 2.

Comment: Is it possible to display 4 videos in one screen?

Comment: I remember I have seen that, based on a OpenGL solution. All video is decoded by the program's own native code using OpenMax interface. And render all the data to the OpenGL surface. So, as long as the CPU power is strong enough, you can render as many videos as you want.

Comment: But. Can I take 4 videoview in one screen?you told that maximum no of instances are 2?so how it is going to possible

Comment: When I say video view, the maximum number of instance is usually 2. When I say GLSurface, you do everything by yourself. No limit technically.